# Openstack slow performance between compute nodes

Tags: performance, openstack, openstack-nova, rdo, openstack-neutron

I have a 2 nodes RDO installation, which went off without any issue. One node is allinone and second node is a compute node, installed as instructed at https://openstack.redhat.com/Adding_a_compute_node

The problem is the network performance on the second compute node. The network speeds on the first node (compute + everything else) is very good. The network speeds in VMs on the second node (compute only) are pathetic - reaching about 10% of the speeds on the first node.

The connectivity between VMs on the second node is fine; reaching almost wire speeds. The connectivity between the *nodes* is fine as well at the same level. BUT, the speeds between VMs on different nodes, or *from* the VMs on the second node are bad:

1. VM to VM on node1: ~1Gbps
2. VM to VM on node2: ~1Gbps
3. Node to Node: ~1Gbps
4. Node1 and VMs on node1 to Internet: wire speeds ~1-2Mbps
5. VMs on node2 to VM on node1: ~70-100Kbps
6. VMs on node2 to Internet: ~200kbps
7. Node2 to the Internet: wire speeds ~1-2Mbps.

I would really appreciate helping to hunt down what's up with the config.

Answer (score 0):

The solution found here: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/30090/network-is-slow-on-compute-node-of-two-node-icehouse-neutron-ovsvlan-centos-65-fedora-20-cluster/; similar problem + working solution.